# What is the difference between "StackOverflow" and "/*Programmers*/"?

Tags: discussion, stackoverflow

I can see that StackOverflow and Programmers are both about programming. Isn't this redundant? Is there a difference?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82988/choosing-between-stack-overflow-and-programmers-stack-exchange

Comment: /* Programmers * / is commented out, I *wish* you could comment out a stack overflow..